# Implementing brute-force autocorrelation method using C

Tags: c, for-loop

I am trying to use C to implement the first autocorrelation formula seen in this Wikipedia article - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation#Properties

I know exactly what I need to do in mathematical terms, but trying to implement this as an iterative process is proving quite tricky.

Eventually I'm going to be using amplitude values imported from a CSV file into an array in order to determine the pitch of a note, but for now I'm using a test array:

```
int sig[] = { 0, 2, 6, 14, 25, 13, 11, 10, 5, 1 };
int N = sizeof(sig) / sizeof(sig[0]);
```

I now need to calculate an output array like so:

```
(sig[0] * sig[N-1]) 
(sig[0] * sig[N-2]) + (sig[1] * sig[N-1])
(sig[0] * sig[N-3]) + (sig[1] * sig[N-2]) + (sig[2] * sig[N-1])
```

and so on...

I have tried implementing this using for loops but I'm not sure how to keep adding a new value every time. sig[0] is always going to be multiplied by sig[N-x], increasing by 1 each time a new iteration is added, and then this new iteration will remain, and the sig[N-x] that is multiplied by will also start to decrease by 1.

I know something such as

```
int n=0;
int m=0;
int a[N];

for(m = 0; m = N-1; m++)
    for(n = N-m; n = 0; n--)
        a[N] = a[N-1] + sig[m] * sig[n-1];
```

won't work as this will just add the previous calculation to the new one, when what actually happens is the two values that are multiplied together keep changing each time

Does anyone have any suggestions? My main issue is that it isn't really an 'iteration', as there are no similar values between each iteration.

Comment: Show your failed attempt, then maybe we can tell you what's wrong. When asking questions on SO you should show your code rather than describe it.

Comment: There are several attempts I've tried, and I know why my code is wrong, I just don't know how to implement what I want to do in C. Though I have added a poor example into the OP

Comment: In addition to previous comment: `int N = sizeof(sig); `->  `int N = sizeof(sig) / sizeof(sig[0]);`.

Comment: Really? Oh that's good to know, I'll change that. For now I know my array is of size 10 so I'll just set it as a constant until I'm working with real data

Comment: Don't set it as a constant, do as I showed in my previous comment.

Comment: `int N = sizeof(sig) / sizeof(sig[0])` will give you the number of elements regardless of the type of `N`.

Comment: That's very useful to know. Do you have any idea about implementing the autocorrelation? I'm starting to think for loops may not be the best option, but I don't know of other alternatives

Comment: Of course you need loops here one or the other way.

Comment: Since it is an iterative thing you are right, otherwise I might as well just write out the individual calculations - though that won't be very useful when working with thousands of data points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
int i, j
int a[N];

for (i = 0; i <= N-1; i++) {
    a[i] = 0; 
    for (j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
        a[i] = a[i] + sig[j] * sig[N-i+j-1]; 
    }
}
```

Compared to the question I have:

- changed the loop conditions from assignments to conditions and fixed the start/end value
- added initilization of output array to 0
- fixed the output array assignment to match the example formulas

Comment: Thank you so much! This works perfectly, and the code isn't too far away from what I was previously attempting